# ЧПУ и Mod_Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite, чпу

В общем, делаю сайт. Нужно сделать ЧПУ через `Mod_Rewrite` в `.htaccess`. Написал такою дребедень:

```
Options All -ExecCGI -Indexes -Includes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dir\/index\.php\?\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/$ dir/index.php?pg=$1 [L]
```

И не работает, хоть тресни. Проверял через var_dump($_GET). Все время выдает только

```
array(1) { ["/somepage/"]=> string(0) "" }
```

В чем дело? Помогите, срочно надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pg=$1 [L]
```